# Saving changes to web.config using System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, webconfigurationmanager

I have created a custom web config section that I can read and modify successfully at runtime. However, it does not physically change the web.config. If the site is restarted or the pool is recycled I lose my changes and it reverts to the original web.config settings.

I would like to be able to persist the changes to the web.config file and I have not been able to figure this out.

My web.config section looks like this:

```
<configSections>
    <section
        name="MyCustomConfig"
        type="MyProject.Configuration.myCustomConfig"
        allowLocation="true"
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"
        /> 
</configSections>

<MyCustomConfig Address="127.0.0.1" 
        OrgId="myorg" 
        User="john"/>
```

Here is my configuration class

```
namespace MyProject.Configuration
{
    public class MyCustomConfig : System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
    {
        // Static accessor
        public static MyCustomConfig Current =
            (MyCustomConfig)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyCustomConfig");

        public void Save()
        {
            if (IsModified())
            {
                // I'm getting here, but can't figure out how to save

            }

        }

        public override bool IsReadOnly()
        {
            return false;

        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("OrgId", DefaultValue = "test", IsRequired = true)]
        public string OrgId
        {
            get { return this["OrgId"].ToString(); }
            set { 
                this["OrgId"] = value; 
            }
        }
        [ConfigurationProperty("Address", DefaultValue="127.0.0.1", IsRequired=true)]
        public string Address {
            get { return this["Address"].ToString();  }
            set { this["Address"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("User", DefaultValue = "", IsRequired = true)]
        public string User
        {
            get {
                if (this["User"] == null) return string.Empty;
                else return this["User"].ToString(); 
            }
            set { this["User"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

In my controller, I modify the settings with the posted form

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ConfigurationViewModel config)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // write changes to web.config
        Configuration.MyCustomConfig.Current.Address = config.SIPAddress;
        Configuration.MyCustomConfig.Current.User = config.User;
        Configuration.MyCustomConfig.Current.OrgId = config.OrgId;
        Configuration.MyCustomConfig.Save()
    }
}
```

In the config class save method, IsModified() returns true, now I just need to get those modifications to file.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to make changes to the configuration file at runtime? This would cause an application pool recycle every time the change is made to the file.

Would it make sense to store these settings in a database and restore them from the db upon start of the application?

I'm simply questioning from a best practices point of view, as I know it's possible, just not recommended.

Comment: I wasn't aware the application pool would recycle on change. Storing in db might be better then.